# Adding elements to an array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I have a list of information returned from the server and I am putting it in arraylist called "items". I  would like to know how I can extract just the departments and place them into a simple string array which I have named department list .

This is what the list looks like

```
[
  {
 "Department": "Mobile Development",
    "Department": 22
  },
  {
    "   "Department": "IT Support",
    "Department": 13
  }]
```

This is what I have coded so far however I think there is a problem with the way I am trying to add in my for each .

```
 private void loadCompanyInfo() {
     //final Context context = this.getActivity();
     final Context context = this.context;
      Organization client = new Organization(context);

      Organization.api(context).getCompanyInforamtion(client.getID()).enqueue(new Callback<Results<CostCentresResult>>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<Results<CostCentresResult>> call, Response<Results<CostCentresResult>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               try {
                  Items = new ArrayList<>();
                  companyInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

                  Items.addAll(response.body());
                  if(Items.contains("Department")) {
                     Items.get(Items.indexOf(0));

                     for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
                        companyInfoList.add(Items[0])
                     }

                  }

               } catch (Exception ex  ) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                  ex.getMessage();
                  ex.getCause();
                  ex.getClass();
               }
            }
         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<Results<CostCentresResult>> call, Throwable t) {
// TODO: handle ex
            Errors.handleException(t);
         }

      });
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you please put your POJO class here ??

Comment: your json is wrong

Comment: I actually just want to know how to extract The departments from the first arraylist (Items) and add them to another arraylist (companyInfoList) ;

Comment: you json array contains two attributes which is having same key. kindly post the correct json array so that we can help you.

Comment: Post correct json and also, Items will be having CostCentresResult POJO list.
You can do get(i) from Arraylist and you will get i th element of array which is of type CostCentresResult.
After that do CostCentresResult.getDepartment, will give you department name.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to get the list of department from your server response:

```
try {
            ArrayList<String> mDepartmentList = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray serverResponseJsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body());
            if (serverResponseJsonArray != null
                    && serverResponseJsonArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < serverResponseJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject departmentJsonObj = serverResponseJsonArray
                            .getJSONObject(i);
                    if (departmentJsonObj != null
                            && !departmentJsonObj.equals("")) {
                        if (departmentJsonObj.has("Department")) {
                            mDepartmentList.add(departmentJsonObj
                                    .getString("Department"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```